# How can I insert the date into the table enter by the user if it is not in that table in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date

I am getting the input from the user as a date and I want to check that if that date is in the table then fetch the data corresponding to that date otherwise insert the date in that table.
I am using the following code and getting problem in the select query. My code is below:

```
package com.foursquaregame.in;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Astro_talk extends Activity{
    EditText dob;
    Button submit;
    SQLiteDatabase db_sunshine=null;
    String Data="";
    String Data1="";
    String TableName="tb_astro";
    String dob_var;
    String date_var;
    String quote;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.astro_talk);
        //quote="Don't worry, Be happy";
        dob=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.dob);
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                java.util.Date dateObject;

                System.out.println("submit data");
                dob_var=dob.getText().toString();
                try {
                    dateObject = sdf.parse(dob_var);
                    date_var = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(dateObject);

                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println(dob_var);
                 try
                    {
                     db_sunshine=Astro_talk.this.openOrCreateDatabase("db_hellosunshine", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                     db_sunshine.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ TableName + " (d_o_b NUMERIC,astro_quote DATE))");
                     Cursor c=db_sunshine.rawQuery("SELECT astro_quote FROM "+ TableName +"WHERE d_o_b='"+ date_var +"'" , null);
                     System.out.println("query executed");
                        int column1=c.getColumnIndex("d_o_b");
                        int column2=c.getColumnIndex("astro_quote");
                        c.moveToFirst();
                        if(c!=null)
                        {   

                            {
                                String date=c.getString(column1);
                                String astro =c.getString(column2);
                                Data=Data+date+"\n";
                                Data1=Data1+astro+"\n";
                                System.out.println("name"+date+" score"+astro);
                            }while(c.moveToNext());
                        }
                        if(Data.equals(dob_var)){
                            RelativeLayout rel_astro=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rel_astro);
                            TextView tv_astro=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_astro);
                            tv_astro.setText(Data);

                            setContentView(rel_astro);
                        }
                        else{
                            db_sunshine.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+TableName+"(d_o_b,astro_quote)"+" VALUES ('"+dob_var+"','"+quote+"');");
                            Toast customToast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
                            customToast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your quote is submit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            customToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                            customToast.show();

                            Intent newIntent = new Intent(Astro_talk.this,selectoption.class);

                            startActivity(newIntent);
                            finishActivity(0);

                        }


                    }catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        Log.e("ERROR","ERROR" ,ex);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if(db_sunshine!=null)
                            db_sunshine.close();
                    }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Please tell me where I am doing something wrong.

Comment: My problem is in the select query which gives me the error sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "=": syntax error

Comment: try this  Cursor mCursor = db.query(TableName ,
    new String[] { "astro_quote " },
    "d_o_b=" + "'" + date_var + "'", null, null, null, null);

Comment: There is one exception arises when i execute my code that Cursor out of bound and index is -1.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Cursor c=db_sunshine.rawQuery("SELECT astro_quote FROM "+ TableName +"WHERE d_o_b='"+ date_var +"'" , null);
                 System.out.println("query executed");
                    int column1=c.getColumnIndex("d_o_b");
                    int column2=c.getColumnIndex("astro_quote");
                    c.moveToFirst();
                    if(c!=null)
                    {   

                        {
                            String date=c.getString(column1);
                            String astro =c.getString(column2);
                            Data=Data+date+"\n";
                            Data1=Data1+astro+"\n";
                            System.out.println("name"+date+" score"+astro);
                        }while(c.moveToNext());
                    }
```

Here you are querying for one column but trying to get two columns
you can get only one date that is 
 int column1=c.getColumnIndex("astro_quote");

String astro =c.getString(column1);

Answer (score 1):

Try using :

```
 Cursor c=db_sunshine.rawQuery("SELECT astro_quote FROM "+ TableName +" WHERE d_o_b="+ date_var, null);
```

I am not sure,these were the only problem but thats might be because you didn't add a space character before WHERE in your query(which i have added in above one).And your d_o_b is numeric then i think,you don't need to use " ' " before and after date_var in your query.

**EDIT :**

It seems from your code that you are trying to access the table just after you create it.So there is no data in table and hence,you will get empty cursor.when you try to access data from that cursor,you are getting exception.

First fill the table with data.and then try to fetch it.

so basically what you need to do is-

```
 db_sunshine=Astro_talk.this.openOrCreateDatabase("db_hellosunshine", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
 db_sunshine.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ TableName + " (d_o_b NUMERIC,astro_quote DATE))");

 // call a function to add data to table ( you will have to add data here to the table created just now )

 Cursor c=db_sunshine.rawQuery("SELECT astro_quote FROM "+ TableName +" WHERE d_o_b="+ date_var, null);
 if(c.getCount()>0)
 {
    // cursor contains data ( which can never be a option for your case )
 }             
 else
 {
   // empty cursor
 }
```

Comment: There is one exception arises when i execute my code that Cursor out of bound and index is -1.

Comment: please try to log c.getCount() just after you execute the query...This is probably because you are having empty table.